# How do I change the context menu on a WPF ESRI Symbol at run time?

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, controltemplate, arcgis, esri

An ESRI Symbol has a ControlTemplate and in the ControlTemplate I can specify a ContextMenu, and that works fine. However, I need to change the ContextMenu (add, remove items) at run time. ControlTemplate.FindName doesn't work because Symbol is not a FrameworkElement. I also know about Graphic.MouseLeftButtonDown, but I want the context menu to appear at right click, if possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the ContextMenuOpening event on your control you can specify the contextmenu there.  This way you can alter it as needed at runtime.